# Socialist Social Plugin not working with Facebook

Tags: jquery, social-media

So I was wondering if any knew why this application does not work when inputting a Facebook ID: http://plugins.in1.com/socialist/ I have downloaded this application and twitter parameter works fine but when I add a facebook parameter, it odes not work. I was wondering if anyone can help me to get it to work, here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../jquery.socialist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='../jquery.socialist.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').socialist({
        networks: [
           {name:'youtube',id:'LoyolaChicago'},
            {name:'facebook',id:'LoyolaChicago'},
           {name:'twitter',id:'LoyolaChicago'},
           {name:'flickr',id:'loyolauniversitychicago'},

           ],
        isotope:false,
        random:false,
        fields:['source','heading','text','date','image','followers','likes']
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'It does not work' does not suffice as an explanation of the scenario.

Comment: yes it does, it does not work

Comment: good luck getting help when you provide NOTING useful.

Answer (score 0):

The page might have a privacy setting on it. When i tried a public page it worked.. not like i wanted it to, but it worked! the fields option stopped mine from working also..